# Discord bot deleting all messages when trigger word is found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey I'm making a discord bot that detects trigger words from a list and then deletes that message and whenever it is detecting a message it will keep deleting every message afterwards, i can't figure out why its doing this.

```
import discord

with open("triggerWords.txt") as file:
    triggers = [trigger.strip().lower() for trigger in file.readlines()]
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if any(trigger in message.content for trigger in triggers):
        await message.delete(limit=1)

client.run('input_token')
```

Answer (score 0):

`message.delete` doesn’t take the `limit` kwarg, simply do:

```py
await message.delete()
```

Also I’m pretty sure this shouldn’t even work, you don’t have any intents enabled and `on_message` requires `intents.messages`